# c_str() results from vector<string> become garbage with libc++

Tags: c++, string, vector, garbage-collection

I am trying to work out why the following C++ code works fine with libstdc++, but with libc++ the `c_str()` results become garbage.

The code simply builds a vector of strings using `savedstrings.push_back("blah")`, and right after each string is added to the vector, `savedstrings.back().c_str()` is added to a separate vector of `const char*`.

So each `const char*` should point to the corresponding string in the `savedstrings` vector. This works fine with libstdc++, but with libc++ the `const char*` at the start of the `cstrs` vector start to become garbage as the later ones are added.

I'm not sure I understand what is going on here. Is the `savedstrings` vector moving the earlier strings as new ones are added, thus invalidating the `c_str()` result? How can I stop this from happening?

```
vector<string> savedstrings;
vector<const char*> cstrs;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  savedstrings.push_back("blah");
  cstrs.push_back(savedstrings.back().c_str());
}

vector<string>::iterator si;
for(si=savedstrings.begin();si!=savedstrings.end();++si)
  cout << *si << endl;

vector<const char*>::iterator ci;
for(ci=cstrs.begin();ci!=cstrs.end();++ci)
  cout << *ci << endl;
```

Comment: Why are you trying to store the `const char*` portion of a `std::string` instead of just storing the actual `std::string`?

Comment: It's a simplified version of a bug I encountered in the [Open Babel](https://github.com/openbabel/openbabel/blob/master/src/ops/loader.cpp) project. Not sure why, but they use `const char*` for their plugin IDs, which are loaded as a vector of strings from a text file.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but in the code section you linked, I see no declarations of `std::vector<const char*>`.  However, storing the `_filename` as a `const char*` is likely a bug itself.  Those member variables should be `std::string`.

Comment: Another option, if `savedstrings` doesn't need contiguous storage, would be change it from a `vector<string>` to `list<string>`. Then your code would work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have any re-allocations in `savedstrings`, the pointers to the underlying string data may become invalid. De-referencing such pointers would yield *undefined behaviour*.

You can avoid re-allocations by reserving the right amount of capacity:

```
vector<string> savedstrings;
savedstrings.reserve(10);
```

Here's an example showing how a vector's capacity grows as you push elements into is (g++ 4.7.3 on some ubuntu x86_64):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v;

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    v.push_back(0);
    std::cout << v.capacity() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2   # re-allocation
4   # re-allocation
4
8   # re-allocation
8
8
8
16  # re-allocation
16
```

Comment: Actually, moving a string is one of the things that invalidates `c_str()` (as it must to support small-string optimization)

Comment: @BenVoigt Right, thanks. I had already started writing a short essay on that, but perhaps it is best to just leave it out.

Comment: So is it the subsequent `push_back("blah")` calls on the vector that invalidate the previous `c_str()` results? If I completely populate the `savedstrings` vector, then in a second loop produce the `c_str()` they will remain valid provided no further changes are made to the `savedstrings` vector?

Comment: @MattSwain Some of the calls to `push_back` would result in the vector needing to increase its capacity, which means it must re-allocate. This invalidates all previously stored pointers. Typically it doubles its capacity each time this happens, and the starting value is implementation dependent. I'll put an example up shortly.

Comment: @MattSwain So, if you call reserve, the capacity is set and there will be no re-allocations until it is exceeded. You can do that, or fill the vector in a first pass and then get the pointers, as you described.

Answer (score 3):

The pointer returned by `c_str()` must be used immediately, it is not intended to be stored for later use.